# MongoDB restoration fails on linux

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

i am facing issue while restoring mongodb it is showing an error
[here the snip for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THZ3l.png)
 ulimit is set to 64000 but still facing this error can any one please help thankx in advance

Comment: Did you dump and restore from the same versions? Post the version details. Most probably the issue is with `metadata.json` file.

Comment: i am using the same version of dump and restore its  r3.2.22